# Rails: When do I use the Apache user and when the Rails user in my automated tasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

I'm currently interning using RoR. I'm having difficulty understanding which user to `sudo su myuser rake myraketask` as. When do I use the rails app user and when do I use the apache user in my tasks? I know it's good practice to just set them both as the same user, but that makes it difficult to understand which one I need to use. When is the Rails user used? When is the Apache user used?

Answer (score 1):

To be safe, I would always run the tasks as the user running the web service, unless you specifically need them run as root.